# vuejs не загружает переменные окружения

Tags: vue.js

Может быть кто-нибудь сможет подсказать, в чём проблема? Не подсасываются переменные из .env. Файлик лежит в корне проекта. Все переменные выглядят так:

```
VUE_APP_*=*
```

В main.js делаю так

```
console.log(process);
```

В консоли получаю так:

```
nextTick: ƒ nextTick(fn)
title: "browser"
execPath: "browser"
arch: "browser"
platform: "browser"
pid: 1
browser: true
env: {}
argv: []
binding: ƒ (name)
cwd: ƒ ()
chdir: ƒ (dir)
uvCounters: ƒ ()
memoryUsage: ƒ ()
uptime: ƒ ()
dlopen: ƒ ()
umask: ƒ ()
kill: ƒ ()
exit: ƒ ()
features: {}
__proto__: Object
```

Куда можно посмотреть? Из-за чего это может происходить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилася относительно просто. Когда-то я уже сталкивался с подобного рода эффектами [vuejs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040341/vuejs-%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F).

В таком случае, к тому моменту, в x могут находиться уже совсем другие данные. 
Я предполагаю, что это связано с тем, что `console.log(x)` буферизирует данные. А к моменту, когда их требуется вывести, по ссылке `x`, может лежать уже что-то ещё.

Для того, чтобы этого избежать, я явно указал поле объекта, которое требуется
посмотреть:

```
console.log(process.env)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте пакет `dotenv` для чтения и дальнейшего доступа к данным из вашего .env файла, можно установить через npm/yarn: "npm/yarn install dotenv" и потом можете использовать, например так и уже из этой переменной получаете нужные значения: const result = dotenv.config() // читает ваш .env файл.

Ссылка на github модуля : https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv .
Ссылка на официальную документацию VUE, которая вам также может быть полезна по этой теме: https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/mode-and-env.html#%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: Тут вопрос не в пакете. А в конкретной проблеме. За пакет спасибо. Изучу. Но ответ, как правильный, отметить не могу.